# Export TableView Data to CSV-file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

How can I export my Tableview Cell Datas to an CSV-File? I will send this csv file as an Email attachment? Thanks for helping!!!

Comment: First thing you need to understand is the difference between a *Model* and a *View*. A UITableView is a *View*. The question you should really be asking is how do I get data out of my Data Model and save it as an email attachment. Is that your real question? Or do you NOT use anything to store data?

Comment: I´m a beginner in swift. So I`m thankful for every help. At the moment i fill tableview cells with arrays. I will store the data only on runtime and export it to csv. When closing the app the data can be lost. So i such for the right way to do this. Must i first store data for exporting to csv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your data is an array (that is your Data Model!) and assuming its contents are type String you can convert it to another comma separated string using a simplified implementation shown below. You need to insert the code after you have done creating the array. Populating the table view is a separate issue unless you are using the table to create or modify the data array. Swift has powerful String handling capability and there is a more compact way of doing this. Also, you have more to do if you want to send the email directly from your view controller or if you want to save it locally or in the cloud.

```
import UIKit

var str = ["A","B","C"]
var csv:String = ""
var tmp = ""
for x in str {
    if x != str.last {
        csv += x+","
    } else {
        csv += x
}
}
```